# Issue in Entry Widget resizing in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the following code to populate Entry widget on tkinter Frame:

```
import tkinter as tk

def populate(frame):
    '''Put in some fake data'''
    for row in range(100):
        tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        tk.Entry(frame, width = 50).grid(row=row, column=1)
    
def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

populate(frame)

root.mainloop()
```

Issue which I am facing in the above code is that when I am resizing the tkinter main window the Entry widget is not resizing itself automatically according to change in window size.

Can someone please help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resize the entries when the tkinter window is resized, you need to:

- resize `frame` when `canvas` is resized

  ```
  def on_canvas_resized(event):
      canvas.itemconfig('frame', width=event.width)

  ...
  canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_canvas_resized)
  ...
  canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw", tag='frame') # added tag
  ```
- make `Entry` to fill the available space horizontally

  ```
  def populate(frame):
      '''Put in some fake data'''
      for row in range(100):
          tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
          tk.Entry(frame, width = 50).grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='ew') # added sticky
  ...
  frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # make column 1 to fill available space horizontally
  ```